# How does ProgressBar drawable work?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar

### Background

I wanted to make a rounded progress bar that is determinate (meaning **android:indeterminate="false"**), so I searched the Internet and found a short answer of Romain Guy, [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/4P65fajMiqc/03tNqh1PA3YJ).

So I grabbed the code and used it in a sample project:

the (part of the) layout file:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/backColor"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="33"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress" />
```

drawable/progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!--    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_circular_background"/> -->
    <item>
        <shape  
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3.4"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="6.0" >
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#ffffffff"
                android:startColor="#ff000000"  
                android:type="sweep"
                android:useLevel="true" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@drawable/progress_particle"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="360" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

screenshots (not exactly of the current code) :

[image]

### The question

It works fine, but I don't understand how it works.

How does the progress bar know what to change exactly on the drawables, and how ?

For example, how does it know how to take only the ring shape from 0 degrees on the right, and not from other places?

Is it possible to customize how it work?

Comment: Why not look at the source code?

Comment: Please provide the underlying Java code.

Comment: @DerGolem this is the code. the java files don't contain anything.

Comment: @323go there is no source code. it's all just xml...

Comment: Look at the *Android* source code. Surely you know it exists?

Comment: @323go oh you meant Android source code. But I think such a thing should be found on the documentation too, so that people would know how to do it.

Comment: I think it works like a "linear" (determinate) ProgressBar. You set a value and the progress indicator jumps to that step. The innings of the component manage how to draw it. No matter wether it's a line, a bar, a wheel, a gear, ... linear or rotative, it knows how to handle the indicator properly.

Comment: @DerGolem yes, it seems to work using setLevel which is found on the Drawable class itself. I wonder if creating a customized drawable allows you to also do it in XML as I've written here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ProgressBar works by changing the **level** of the associated drawable. In `doRefreshProgress()`:

```
final int level = (int) (scale * MAX_LEVEL);
(progressDrawable != null ? progressDrawable : d).setLevel(level);
```

A [Drawable's level](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setLevel%28int%29) is, basically, an integer number that may have different meanings for different kinds of `Drawable` subclasses.

> This allows a drawable to vary its imagery based on a continuous
>   controller, for example to show progress or volume level.
>
> Returns true if this change in level has caused the appearance of the Drawable to change (hence requiring an invalidate), otherwise returns false.

In particular, a `GradientDrawable` (with `useLevel="true"`, such as this one) uses the level value to know which fraction of the drawable should be drawn. For example, for a *left-to-right linear gradient*, the rectangle is calculated as:

```
final float level = st.mUseLevel ? (float) getLevel() / 10000.0f : 1.0f;    
x0 = r.left;            y0 = r.top;
x1 = level * r.right;   y1 = y0;
```

In the case of a *ring* gradient such as this one, the level determines what fraction of the total 360 deg angle should be drawn:

```
float sweep = st.mUseLevelForShape ? (360.0f * getLevel() / 10000.0f) : 360f;
```

In short, as the `setProgress()` method is called, this value changes, and the ring is progressively filled.

As for the `RotateDrawable`, it uses the same exact mechanism to rotate the `progress_particle` bitmap (which is just a transparent square with a white dot at 90 deg) around its center:

```
mState.mCurrentDegrees = mState.mFromDegrees +
    (mState.mToDegrees - mState.mFromDegrees) * ((float) level / MAX_LEVEL);
```

Finally, about the *"how does it know how to take only the ring shape from 0 degrees on the right"* part, that's just a matter of convention. Ring GradientDrawables start from the right. The first lines in the ring path calculation are:

```
// inner top
ringPath.moveTo(x + radius, y);
// outer top
ringPath.lineTo(x + radius + thickness, y);
```

Comment: Interesting. so how would you customize those drawables, so that they would start from a different angle?  Also, is it possible to extend from those drawables and use them in XML, just as it's possible to do it with customized views inside layout files ?

Comment: 1) Possibly by creating a new `<rotate>` drawable that references this one in its `drawable` attribute? Haven't tested this though. 2) No, see the answer by Diane Hackborn [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/FA6p2JkkNNc)

Comment: 1.+2. too bad. I wonder why they didn't make it as advanced as on views... Anyway, thanks.