# Determinate Circular Progressbar around Button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-progressbar

I need to give scanning functionality in my android app. This is how my design looks like:

[image]

I want to put circular `progressbar` (Yellow in colour) around the Scan Button. I have seen may tutorials but all of these put text inside the `progressbar`.

This is what I have achieved so far:

[image]

Through this code:

XML:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/scan"
        android:background="@drawable/scan_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

NOTE: Setting `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for `<ProgressBar>` makes it hidden behind the `<Button>`.

JAVA:

```
Button ScanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanbutton);
ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
ScanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(status < 100)
                {
                    status += 1;
                    ScanScreen.this.progressbar.setProgress(status);
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

PROBLEM 1: `progressbar` is indeterminate and placement is not right.

PROBLEM 2: JAVA code works for horizontal progressbar but crashes for circular one when the `button` is clicked.

I know my problem is quite detailed. You don't need to solve it completely, just give me right directions.

Comment: read your error stacktrace, it tells you what you are doing wrong for the second problem. I think you'll have to make a rather custom component to display that sort of progress

Comment: You should be able to get that effect by providing a custom drawable for the progress bar. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915561/how-does-progressbar-drawable-work/23924820 -- it should point you in the right direction.