# How can I add extra shapes to a ProgressBar that move along with progress?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I was given a design for a custom `ProgressBar` that looks like this:

[image]

The way it works is that the bar is completely blue at `0` progress, and as progress is incremented, each side fills in equally white toward the center until the entire bar is white at `max` progress.

I've got the bar set up just fine. I'm using two `ProgressBar` objects, one that moves left-to-right, and the other rotated so that it moves right-to-left.

The part I'm stuck at is how to draw those extra circle shapes that move toward the center along with the white progress `<clip>`. I tried just adding an extra `<shape>` to my `<clip>` item in the XML, but that stretched the circle out as if it was using the circles to fill in the bar.

Is there a way I can add these extra shapes to the `ProgressBar` XML itself, or do I need to create another `drawable` for these shapes and then update their position manually in code? I'm not sure what the correct approach is here and I haven't been able to find any similar examples in my research. Any help is appreciated!

Here's the XML I'm using for the `progressDrawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#29A4DD"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#F05926"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: just use one `PrograessBar` with a custom `Drawable`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30873744/2252830) on how to create one, this `Drawable` is ready for use with `setProgressDrawable`

Comment: While I'm aware pretty much anything can be done programatically with a custom `Drawable`, I'm unfamiliar with drawing that way and would like to save myself some time researching if I can accomplish this in XML. For example, Romain Guy accomplished something similar to what I want within a circular `ProgressBar`, so it seems it would be possible for a horizontal bar as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915561/how-does-progressbar-drawable-work?rq=1